# Expectation of exponential of Ito Integral

Tags: exponential-function, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I need to calculate the covariance of two exponentials of Ito integrals, where B is Brownian motion: $$ \text{Cov}\left[ \text{exp}\left(\int_0^t f(u)dB_u \right) , \text{exp}\left(\int_0^s f(u)dB_u \right) \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[e^{I(t)}e^{I(s)} \right] - \mathbb{E}\left[e^{I(t)} \right]\mathbb{E}\left[e^{I()} \right]$$

I am having trouble understanding how to calculate:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[ \text{exp}\left(\int_0^t f(u)dB_u \right) \right] $$

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: If $f$ is deterministic, then $\int_0^t f(u)\,\mathrm d B_u\sim \mathcal N\left(0, \int_0^t f(u)^2\,\mathrm d u\right)$.

Comment: f is deterministic but what about $exp(I(t))$? How is that distributed?
Is it somehow related to the moment generating function?

Comment: @AngeloManna as Surb said $\xi = \int_0^t f(u) d B_u \sim N(0, \int_0^t f^2(u)du)$, hence we need to calculate $\mathbb{E}(e^{\xi})$ this is just an Lebesgue integral